# PHP PDO Database class parameter passing

Tags: php, oop, pdo, sqlsrv

I would like to setup an array with multiple parameters in it, pass it to my database class. Currently I can only send one parameter, but generally my sql queries have multiple parameters.

**Sample database method:**

```
public function fetchQuery($sql,$params,$conn){
    try{
        $queryparams=array($params);
        $x=$conn->prepare($sql);
        $x->execute($queryparams);
        $rArray = $x->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $rArray;
    }catch (Exception $e){
        die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) );
    }
}
```

**Call to database method:**

```
        $params=$vendID;
        $sql = "SELECT Email from Contact WHERE VendID = ?";

 try{
          $emails=$db->fetchQuery($sql,$params,$conn);
          $eCount = count($emails);
           if($eCount>0){
                foreach($emails as $row){
                    $eArray[]=$row['Email'];
                }
            }else{
                echo "No email addresses associated with this vendor";
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) );
        }
```

Now say my sql query was like: "Select * from Contact where CustID=? and Expired=?"
How would I build an array and pass the into my function?

Every time I try, I get an array to string conversion error.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now say my sql query was like: "Select * from Contact where CustID=?
>   and Expired=?" How would I build an array and pass the into my
>   function?

I would remove the `$queryparams=array($params);` part of your code, and always pass the function an array even if it has only one elements.

```
$params= array($custID);
$sql = "SELECT Email from Contact WHERE VendID = ?";

try{
    $emails=$db->fetchQuery($sql,$params,$conn);
```

mutiple

```
$params= array($vendID, $expired);
$sql = "Select * from Contact where CustID=? and Expired=?";

try{
    $emails=$db->fetchQuery($sql,$params,$conn);
```

---

I personaly prefer the named parameter, where I can use the associative arrays:

```
$sql = "Select * from Contact where CustID= :custId and Expired= :expired";

$params= array(':custId'=>$custID, 
               ':expired'=>$expired
);
```

Comment: please explain the downvote, Im getting tired of this.. if you see something wrong **SAY** something!!!

Answer (score 2):

In your fetchQuery method you can check if $params is already an array or not.

```
<?php
if (is_array($params)) {
    $queryParams = $params;
}
else {
    $queryParams = array($params);
}
```

Comment: Please explain how I can improve my answer, or what is unclear, instead of (or in addition to) downvoting

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need this function. it saves you typing of just a couple words.
Yet the same time it is limiting you in using PDO. Look at your code with raw pdo

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT Email from Contact WHERE VendID = ?");
$stmt->execute([$vendID]);
$emails = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
if(!$emails){
    echo "No email addresses associated with this vendor";
}
```

it's 3 times shorter than with your function.
PDO already is a wrapper by itself. One need VERY strong reasons and too much experience to be able to extend it proficiently.